# Outlook VBA script - find and replace text with image

Tags: microsoft-outlook, vba

I have a e-commerce store. When I get a sale, I receive an order confirmation email which contains the name of the product sold. When the email comes through, I would like to run a script that replaces the product name eg. "red widget", with a picture of that product. Is that possible?

I have found a similar code to replace text (set of numbers in this case) with a link, but I need it to replace with a picture instead.

```
Option Explicit

Sub InsertHyperLink(MyMail As MailItem)
    Dim body As String, re As Object, match As Variant

    body = MyMail.body
    Set re = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    re.Pattern = "#[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"

    For Each match In re.Execute(body)
        body = Replace(body, match.Value, "http://example.com/bug.html?id=" & Right(match.Value, 6), 1, -1, vbTextCompare)
    Next

    MyMail.body = body
    MyMail.Save
End Sub
```

#### example mail

> Order Confirmation
>
> Thanks for shopping with us today!
>   ------------------------------------------------------
>   Order Number: 2209
>   Date Ordered: Friday 28 June, 2013
>
> Products
>   ------------------------------------------------------
>   1 x red widget = $5.00
>   ------------------------------------------------------
>   Total: $0.00
>
> Delivery Address
>   xxx

search text: "red widget"
replace picture: redwidget.jpg

Comment: Welcome to superuser, VBA questions are ON topic on superuser. Can you give an example mail, example search text and an example picture pls?

Comment: have updated with sample email

Comment: First, you need two fix strings which wrap the product name because the product name can vary. Maybe `x` and `=` (together with its leading and ending blanks) will work? Check some more mails, if the text between those two identifiers will always get you the product name. Then we can talk about coding.

Comment: ok just has a look, i guess the product name will always be between x and =

Comment: You want it to convert what you received? That is probably better handled by the ecommerce functions

Comment: Cross-post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17357873/outlook-vba-script-find-and-replace-text-with-image